# React native screens not re-rendering when custom hook state got changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am using a custom hook in app purchases.

```
const useInAppPurchase = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthGlobal)

  const [isFullAppPurchased, setIsFullAppPurchased] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`InAppPurchase useEffect is called`)

    getProductsIAP()

    return async () => {
      try {
        await disconnectAsync()
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  }, [])

  ....
}
```

When I used this hook at `AccountScreen` (where I do the purchase) Account screen is getting re-rendered once the payment is done.

i.e. `isFullAppPurchased` is changing from `false` -> `true`

```
const AccountScreen = (props) => {
  const width = useWindowDimensions().width

  const {
    isFullAppPurchased,
  } = useInAppPurchase()

  return (
    // value is true after the purchase
    <Text>{isFullAppPurchased}</Text>
  )
}
```

But I am using the same hook in `CategoryList` screen and after the payment is done when I navigate to the `CategoryList` screen, The values (isFullAppPurchased) is not updated (still false).
But when I do the re-rendering manually then I get `isFullAppPurchased` as `true`.

```
const CategoryList = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const { isFullAppPurchased } = useInAppPurchase()
   
  return (
    // still value is false
    <Text>{isFullAppPurchased}</Text>
  )
}
```

What is the reason for this behaviour ? How should I re-render `CategoryList` screen once the payment is done ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I see hook make API request only on mount, if whole parent component didn't unmount and rendered a new, value of hook stays same.
E.g. dependencies array is empty - `[]` so hook doesn't request data again.

Probably better idea is to pass *isFullAppPurchased* via context or redux from top level.
And put state and function to update that state in same place.

Comment: Okay got it, Thanks.